# Rewrite rule from old link to new link on same domain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I tried to make a redirect from:

> www.myUrl.nl/my-old-link

to:

> www.myUrl.nl/my-new-link

I already added some redirects in my Apache and those are working fine.

I've tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/my-old-link$
RewriteRule (.*) /my-new-link [R=301]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/my-old-link$
RewriteRule (.*) /my-new-link [R=301]
```

But both don't work. I just stay on www.myUrl.nl/my-old-link.

Answer (score 0):

You should only need:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/my-old-link /my-new-link [R,L]
```

If in your .htaccess file `^/my-old-link` should be `^my-old-link`